# reducing the modulus of a Dirichlet character

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Let $\chi$ be a Dirichlet character modulo $N$. Let $M$ be a positive divisor of $N$
such that $$\text{radical}(N)=\text{radical}(M).$$ Is $\chi$ be a character modulo $M$?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "no". Consider the following example. There is a Dirichlet character modulo 4 defined by
$$ \chi_4(n) = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if $n = 1 \bmod 4$} \\
-1 & \text{if $n = -1 \bmod 4$}\\
0 & \text{if $n$ is even}.\end{cases}$$
Then $\chi_4$ is a Dirichlet character modulo $N = 4$; $M = 2$ is a positive divisor of $N$ which has the same radical as $N$; but $\chi_4$ is not a Dirichlet character modulo 2 (since evidently $\chi_4(1) \ne \chi_4(3)$).